# libssh2.dll is missing when trying to push to github

Tags: git, windows-7

I had a working git installation.

Yesterday I tried to push to github, but I got an error from git-remote-https.exe

> the program can not start because libssh2.dll is missing from your computer. Try to reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I uninstall/reinstall git but the error is still there. Why am I getting this error?

I am using mysys git on windows 7.

Comment: are you using https or ssh to access the repository?

Comment: @michas:  https. The remote url is as follow:  "https://username:password@github.com/org/repository.git"